# Get ids of all elements using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

There are 5 iframe elements in a page and I am trying to find the ids of all the 5 elements using protractor.

What is the right way

```
element.all(by.tagName('iframe')).then(function(arr) {
    console.log("lenthg" ,arr.length) //prints 5
        arr.forEach(function(arr1) {
            console.log("arr1", arr1.getAttribute('id'))
        });
});
```

This code does not give the ids, just prints the element object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the element object, because the function `getAttribute` returns a promise (see [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute)).

So you have multiple possibilities to get your ids.

**1. Option**

You print the id within the `then`-method.

```
element.all(by.tagName('iframe')).then(function(arr) {
    console.log("lenthg" ,arr.length) //prints 5
    arr.forEach(function(arr1) {
        arr1.getAttribute('id').then(function(id) {
            console.log("arr1", id);
        });
    });
});
```

**2. Option**

You can wait for all 5 promises to resolve and the process the ids afterwards.

```
element.all(by.tagName('iframe')).then(function(arr) {
    console.log("lenthg" ,arr.length) //prints 5

    let idPromises = arr.map(function(arr1) {
        return arr1.getAttribute('id');
    });

    Promise.all(idPromises).then(function(ids) {
        ids.forEach(function(id) {
            console.log(id);
        });
    });

});
```

**3. Option**

You can use `async` and `await` so you can write synchronous code.

```
it('Your Test Name', async function() {

    ...

    let arr = await element.all(by.tagName('iframe'));
    console.log('lenth', arr.length) //prints 5

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let id = await arr[i].getAttribute('id');
        console.log("arr1", id);
    };

})
```